# React-Native iOS Launch Options not received by Native Module

Tags: ios, swift, react-native, push-notification, notifications

When the app is launched by opening a notification, the `launchOptions` given by iOS to the function `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` does have the notification object but that dictionary never gets passed around to the native module through RCTBridge. Is there a way to get the `launchOptions` in the native module? or am I missing something here?

My AppDelegate `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    [FIRApp configure];
    [FIRMessaging messaging].delegate = self;
    NSURL *jsCodeLocation;

    jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" fallbackResource:nil];

    RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBundleURL:jsCodeLocation
                                                        moduleName:@"myModuleName"
                                                 initialProperties:nil
                                                     launchOptions:launchOptions];
    rootView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:1.0f green:1.0f blue:1.0f alpha:1];

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
    UIViewController *rootViewController = [UIViewController new];
    rootViewController.view = rootView;
    self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Code in my Module in Swift to get `launchOptions`

```
// launchOptions is always nil
let notification: Any = self.bridge.launchOptions?[UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey.remoteNotification] as Any;
```